# adding jquery to react component and update state

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker

I have `checkin` and `checkout` fields and am trying to integrate `pickaday jquery datepicker` to my react component [pickaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday). I have both checkin and checkout fields as state in parent component and pass them as props to the `datepicker` component which I created. what I done is use the `componentDidMount` to initialize the `datepicker` and it works as expected. The issue here is that I can only set the minDate initially and after that its not updating value from props as the state changes.

**DatePicker.js.jsx**

```
var DatePicker = React.createClass({
//This is a callback to parent component for updating the state
    changeDuration: function (date) {
        this.props.onChange(this.props.name, date);
    },


    componentDidMount: function () {
        var _self = this;

        var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById(this.props.name),
            format: 'D MMM YYYY',
            onSelect: function () {
                _self.changeDuration(this.getMoment().toDate())
            },
            minDate: this.props.minDate
        });
    },


    render: function () {
        return (
            <input type="text" id={this.props.name} defaultValue={this.props.value}/>
        )
    }
});
```

In parent component I call above component like this(the `minDate` I pass will only work on initial load and not working after that??)

```
          {/*Checkin and checkout dates*/}
            <div className="col s12 m6 l6 rd-custom-input">
                <DatePicker name={'checkIn'} value={this.props.checkIn}
                            onChange={this.handleNamedChange} minDate={this.props.checkIn}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col s12 m6 l6 rd-custom-input">
                <DatePicker name={'checkOut'} value={this.props.checkOut}
                            onChange={this.handleNamedChange} minDate={this.props.checkIn}/>
            </div>
```

I suspect `componentDidMount` the wrong place to update state when selecting a `date` on `datepicker`. Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here??

Comment: I would personally not use any jQuery UI library with React and find a React specific library to use. The main problem is that both jQuery and React want to be in control of the DOM and be able to mutate the DOM. You can run into cases where jQuery updates the DOM/UI and React notices something changed but it didn't change it. It will then rerender the DOM the way it wants it to be. You may not be having that type of issue but wanted to bring it to your attention

Comment: @finalfreq yes..I think you are right here..but all datepicker libraries I found for react uses webpack and I find it difficult to use with rails asset pipeline. jquery library is easy to integrate without any other dependencies in my case if worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `componentDidMount` lifecycle event is fired once the component is mounted and what you're looking for is to do something at `render` method.

```
var DatePicker = React.createClass({

    picker: null,

    changeDuration: function (date) {
        this.props.onChange(this.props.name, date);
    },


    componentDidMount: function () {
        var _self = this;

        var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById(this.props.name),
            format: 'D MMM YYYY',
            onSelect: function () {
                _self.changeDuration(this.getMoment().toDate())
            },
            minDate: this.props.minDate
        });

        this.picker = picker;
    },


    render: function () {

        if(this.picker){
          this.picker.setMinDate(this.props.minDate);
        }
        return (
            <input type="text" id={this.props.name} defaultValue={this.props.value}/>
        )
    }
});
```

So in this case you store the picker at the class property called `picker` and later on render you can call it's `gotoDate` method.

Comment: This works. But gotoDate didnt work but setMinDate worked. I proposed an edit. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @Abhilash I rejected that, my bad. I thought that was an invalid edit as I saw on the plugin page at the API section such a method.